# python keyword continue is shifting control to finally keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, keyword

I am actually new to python. While learning it I came across this piece of code.

Python official document says when encounter with continue statement, 
control will shift to the beginning of the loop, but in this case it is shifting to final statement and executing from there onward. Is this a bug in python or what? Can somebody please explain this to me? Thanks.

```
def askint():

 while True:

    try:
        val =int(input("pleas enter an  integer  "))
    except:
        print ("it seems like you did'n enter an integer ")
        continue
    else:
        print ("yep that's an integer thank you")
        break

    finally:
        print ('control is now on finally me')  
    print ('i am also getting executed     ')       



askint()
```

Comment: It's flow control. You have a `try/except` in the `while`, not just a bare `while`

Comment: The ```finally``` block is *always* being executed *after* each ```except``` and ```else``` block of the same ```try``` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stated in the [documentation for the `continue` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement):

> When continue passes control out of a try statement with a finally clause, *that finally clause is executed before really starting the next loop cycle*.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Yes, without the `while` loop present, you'd have a `SyntaxError` popping up; since `continue` is inside the `while` and `finally` always gets a chance at finalizing things; it gets executed on the way out.

Comment: so actually the  code is not using correct styling right ?

Comment: It isn't bad styling, it's just that `finally` isn't really needed here. `finally` should be used if you want to do some clean up action; if you don't need to do that, you don't use it @sky_1

Answer (score 2):

The `finally` code is always executed in a `try/except` block.

The `continue` doesn't skip it (or it would be a bug in python).

Answer (score 1):

The `finally` clause **must be executed** no matter what happens, and so it is.

This is why it's called `finally`: it doesn't matter whether what you have *tried* succeeded or raised an *except*ion, it is *always* executed.

Answer (score 0):

finally will be executed always in a try/exept no matter what is the exception.I think this material will help you https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-341.html